# Using Data with ContentsOfUrl

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code snippet here:

```
let endpointURL = URL(string: "http://foobar.com")

let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: endpointURL!, completionHandler: { url, response, error in

    if (error == nil) {

        let dataObject =  NSData(contentsOfURL: endpointURL!)

        let jsonArray: Array = JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as Array 


    }
})

downloadTask.resume()
```

And I'm having this issue:

```
Ambiguous use of 'init(contentsOfURL:)' for NSData part
```

How can I make it unambiguous?

Comment: This is Swift. Use `Data`, not `NSData`. And don't use `Array`. Declare a Swift array of a specific type such as `[String]` or `[[String:Any]]` or whatever it needs to be.

Comment: Your syntax is nonsensical because you are going to load the data directly from `endpointURL`. Either use `dataTask` ->  the returned `data` parameter or use `downloadTask` ->  the returned `url` parameter. In your case – the returned data is JSON – `dataTask` is the appropriate API

Comment: If I use Data, I get: Argument labels '(contentsOfURL:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: I fixed it to use [String], thanks!

Comment: PS: And you are mixing up Swift 2 (`NSData(contentsOfURL`, `JSONObjectWithData` ) and Swift 3 (`URL(string:`) code. This code cannot compile.

Comment: What should Data be in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use something like this in Swift 3, to load JSON data `dataTask` is more appropriate than `downloadTask`.

```
let endpointURL = URL(string: "http://foobar.com")

let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: endpointURL!) { data, response, error in

    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    do {
        // the assumed result type is `[[String:Any]]` cast it to the expected type
        if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
            print(jsonArray)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)